# Как обработать данные из одного файла и вставить эти данные в другой файл?

Tags: c++

Программу нужно реализовать с использованием ifstream и ofstream на языке C++. Увы, мне не удалось найти ни одного ресурса, где описывался бы ход решения этой задачи. Сейчас я опишу то, как я хочу, чтобы это работало:
Допустим, в некотором файле хранятся значения: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6. Мне нужно прочитать эти данные, обработать их (например поделить на два) и вывести получившийся результат в другой файл. Возникла проблема с этапом: прочитать и обработать. При преобразовании string в int выскакивает ошибка `Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FFD9E43478C в cplusplus.exe: исключение Microsoft C++: std::invalid_argument по адресу памяти 0x0000007875DEEB80` и кидает на класс string к строке `if (_Errno_ref == ERANGE) {_Xout_of_range("stoi argument out of range");}`. Что это значит? Как исправить? Я новичок в C++ изучаю язык только 2 недели, не кидайте тапками.
Вот код:

```
        fin.open(path);
        string str;
        int a;

        if (!fin.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Файл открыт!" << endl;

            while (!fin.eof())
            {
                str = "";
                getline(fin, str);
                a = stoi(str);
                cout << a << endl;                
            }
        }
        fin.close();
        ofstream fouts; 
        fouts.open("output.txt"); 
        fouts << a / 2;
        fouts.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, собственно, и все. Разве что нет защиты от дурака - всех проверок существования файла etc...

```
ifstream in("filename");
ofstream out("filename");
int i;
while(in >> i) out << i/2 << " ";
```

Comment: О боги, оно работает! Спасибо большое! Посоветуйте ,пожалуйста, где можно узнать про файловый ввод-вывод? Той информации, что есть в интернете, очень мало, чтобы реализовать полноценное приложение.

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устроил — то принять его можно "птичкой" слева от него. Что до материалов... Да их множество. http://cppstudio.com/post/446/ https://purecodecpp.com/archives/2751 https://kvodo.ru/urok-10-1-rabota-s-tekstovyimi-faylami-v-c.html Да просто сделайте запрос "работа с файлами в C++"...